# Get name of generic type, where generic must extend another type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a generic function, like:

```
func register<T: Component>(factory: () -> T) {
    // name is always Component, I'd like it to be
    // the concrete implementation
    let name = "\(T.self)"
}
```

And I'd like to get the name of the class I'm passing in, for example:

With this protocol:

```
protocol Component { }
```

And this class:

```
class Something : Component { }
```

I want `register` to know about `Something` and not `Component`:

```
register() { Something() } // "name" should be "Something"
```

However, I'm always getting `Component`.  So, in the register function, how can I get the name of the concrete implementation of `T`

If I make `register` look like:

```
func register<T: component>(_: T.Type, factory: () -> T)
```

And then call it like:

```
register(Something.self) { Something() }
```

It works, but I'd rather not have to specify, as it should be inferred.

Comment: [It's working fine for me](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57cae61cfb6d6c7281e049e4)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a specific Idea of what the input is, you can do an if let statement, or a switch.

```
    if let comp = T as? String {
        //you now have a constant called comp that is a string
    }else if let comp = T as? Int {
        //comp is Int, if comp is an int, you still have T if you want to use it
    }//and continue for however long you want
```

I am not sure why you would want to have the name of the class in a String, but you seem to have done that already?

In objective C you can do `T.class`, and other useful functions could be `T.superClass()` or `T.isSubclass(of: String)` depending on your intentions.